# Will I be able to purchase items from steam market after additional credit transfer?

Tags: steam

I am waiting for steam market to become available (still in pending due to "30 days after first purchase ever" restriction). Unfortunately I noticed I won't be able to purchase what I want for the kind of money I got on my steam account.

What troubles me is that I heard after each money transfer, you also need to wait another 30 days. Is it true?

If so, is there another way of not waiting for credit transfer, cause the main reason I need it asap (next week) is my godson's birthdays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no delay . when i add steam credits i am able to purchase instantly so there will should be no issues.

The only difference is if it is the first time you have used the card to add funds. in which case it is only a few days delay as displayed here.

My full answer is there will never be a 30 day delay from adding funds. and the only delay is on the first time not everytime

***Edit:*** the other option is to buy a prepaid steam card and then redeem the credit, this will take instant affect and you won't receive a delay. these can be bought it approved shops and from some online sites. can't tell you exactly where without knowing where you live but a quick google search will let you know.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @user2383572 What COULD get you a delay in transferring funds to your steam account is if you're using a new device that you haven't used before to transfer funds.

Comment: I think that you also need to have Steam Guard activated for at least 15 days. Maybe you should check that for improving your answer. :)